# PS2 disc barely spinning read error

Tags: hardware, ps2

I recently bought 3 old used ps2 discs, and all of them get the same error.  "The disc could not be read."  I am using a ps2 slim.  Some games work on my ps2, but all of these dont.  The only difference I noticed between the ones that work and the ones that dont, is that when i open the disc drive while the disc is reading, the ones that work are spinning fast, and the ones that dont are barely spinning.  Is there a way to fix this?  (the discs *are* pretty scratched, but so are some ones that work)

Update:  I put the disc in my pc, and it was able to read it, not sure if that means its my ps2 thats the problem or not.

Comment: Are they PAL discs trying to run on an NTSC system, or vice versa?

Comment: I'm not sure, exactly, how do i tell? Shouldn't a PS2 disc work on *any* PS2 console?

Comment: The game box will have a serial on it, something like SLUS-XXXX, if it's US (which is NTSC). Even modern consoles have region locked games, and it was even more common back in the day.

Comment: The games have NTSC on them and I'm positive my console is an american console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as Kaizerwolf pointed out in the comments, make sure that the region of the console matches the region of the disc. The PS2 regions are NTSC-U/C (US and Canada), NTSC-J (Japan), NTSC-C (China) and PAL. On the console is on the same sticker as the model, and on the discs is usually under the PlayStation logo.

If the regions match, then you probably have a miscalibrated or burned laser, as you mention that the disc spins just fine. You can try to do stuff like align the laser or change the voltage, but they are advanced tasks that would require a complete disassembly of the console and it would probably be better to just replace them at this point.

Comment: actually I said that the disc is *spinning* but a lot slower than the discs that work.  Thanks for the answer!  =)

Comment: The PS2 is probably confused between a CD and a DVD, as a DVD runs faster than a CD so this might be why is spinning slower.

Comment: How do i tell which one my disc is?

Comment: I found [Here](http://dictionary.sensagent.com/List%20of%20PlayStation%202%20CD-ROM%20games/en-en/) and [Here](https://forum.digitpress.com/forum/showthread.php?78768-Master-List-of-PS2-CD-Based-Games) a couple of lists with PS2 games that were shipped in CD-ROM instead of DVD-ROM. I'm not sure if the list is accurate but is worth checking out.

Comment: Well, I guess these things you sort of have to play by ear.  It's possible the discs dont work, and the consoles fine, I guess I'll find out eventually.  Thnx for the help!  =)